# Bootstrap 4 responsive sidebar menu window resize

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm trying to get the left sidebar to become a small icon (=more settings) when window is resized for small devices.

Issue:

Here is my code and when you resize the window to at about medium you can see an overlap of the two columns. How can I keep it simple and fix this overlap using mainly bootstrap 4 if possible? If I took the navbar class and collapse out, there is not an overlap. Thank you for the help.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<div class="row no-gutters" style="margin-left: 15px;margin-right: 15px;">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-md navbar-expand-sm">
                <button id="filter_control" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#filter_container3" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <p><i class="fas fa-sliders-h" style="padding-right:5px;"></i>=More Settings&nbsp;</p>
                </button>
            <!--collapse for filter and flex-column to make narrow column-->
                <div id="filter_container3" class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="margin-top:50px;">
    
                    <div class="list-group text-secondary">
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="404.html"><span>Account</span></a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="account.html"><span>Subject</span></a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><span>Class</span></a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><span>Schedule</span></a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><span>Log</span></a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><span>Billing</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    
    
    <!--mid col-->
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-10">
            <div class="row no-gutters" style="margin-top:25px;">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 justify-content-sm-center justify-content-lg-center" style="margin: 0px;margin-top: 0px;padding: 10px;">
                    <div class="card bg-success">
                        <div class="card-header" style="padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
                            <h6 class="text-truncate text-center text-white">Appt</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body" style="padding: 12px;">
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-truncate text-white">Coming</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-right" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-white"><i class="far fa-calendar-check" style="opacity: 1;"></i></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row no-gutters text-right">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h5 class="text-white">4</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div><a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 justify-content-sm-center justify-content-lg-center" style="margin: 0px;margin-top: 0px;padding: 10px;">
                    <div class="card bg-primary">
                        <div class="card-header" style="padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
                            <h6 class="text-truncate text-center text-white">Messages</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body" style="padding: 12px;margin: 0px;">
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-truncate text-white">New</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-right" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-white"><i class="far fa-comment"></i></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row no-gutters text-right">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h5 class="text-white">2</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 justify-content-sm-center justify-content-lg-center" style="margin: 0px;margin-top: 0px;padding: 10px;">
                    <div class="card bg-warning">
                        <div class="card-header" style="padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
                            <h6 class="text-truncate text-center text-white">Log</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body" style="opacity: 1;padding: 12px;">
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-truncate text-white">Hours</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-right" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-white">4 <i class="far fa-clock"></i></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h4 class="text-right text-white"></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h5 class="text-right text-white">50</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 justify-content-sm-center justify-content-lg-center" style="margin: 0px;margin-top: 0px;padding: 10px;">
                    <div class="card bg-info">
                        <div class="card-header" style="padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
                            <h6 class="text-truncate text-center text-white">Reviews</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body" style="padding: 12px;">
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-truncate text-white">Total</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-right" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-white">3.5 <i class="fa fa-star"></i></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row no-gutters text-right">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h5 class="text-white">145 Reviews</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div><a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col">
                    <div>
                        <form></form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Excellent and thorough, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that the content is bigger than the parent column so you can simply just adjust the font size, the padding or both and you could add this in a media query at the desired widths.  You could try something like the following:

```
nav .list-group-item {font-size:12px;padding:.75rem .75rem;}
```

That should do the trick.  If it were me just for looks I would give the `.list-group` and the `.list-group-item` a width of 100% as well.  This isn't necessary I just think it looks better and figured I would suggest it so that would be:

```
nav .list-group{width:100%;}
nav .list-group-item {width:100%;font-size:12px;padding:.75rem .75rem;}
```

Here is your updated snippet with that change:

```css
nav .list-group{width:100%;}
nav .list-group-item {width:100%;font-size:12px;padding:.75rem .75rem;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<div class="row no-gutters" style="margin-left: 15px;margin-right: 15px;">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-md navbar-expand-sm">
                <button id="filter_control" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#filter_container3" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <p><i class="fas fa-sliders-h" style="padding-right:5px;"></i>=More Settings&nbsp;</p>
                </button>
            <!--collapse for filter and flex-column to make narrow column-->
                <div id="filter_container3" class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="margin-top:50px;">
    
                    <div class="list-group text-secondary">
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="404.html"><span>Account</span></a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="account.html"><span>Subject</span></a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><span>Class</span></a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><span>Schedule</span></a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><span>Log</span></a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><span>Billing</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    
    
    <!--mid col-->
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-10">
            <div class="row no-gutters" style="margin-top:25px;">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 justify-content-sm-center justify-content-lg-center" style="margin: 0px;margin-top: 0px;padding: 10px;">
                    <div class="card bg-success">
                        <div class="card-header" style="padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
                            <h6 class="text-truncate text-center text-white">Appt</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body" style="padding: 12px;">
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-truncate text-white">Coming</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-right" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-white"><i class="far fa-calendar-check" style="opacity: 1;"></i></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row no-gutters text-right">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h5 class="text-white">4</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div><a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 justify-content-sm-center justify-content-lg-center" style="margin: 0px;margin-top: 0px;padding: 10px;">
                    <div class="card bg-primary">
                        <div class="card-header" style="padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
                            <h6 class="text-truncate text-center text-white">Messages</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body" style="padding: 12px;margin: 0px;">
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-truncate text-white">New</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-right" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-white"><i class="far fa-comment"></i></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row no-gutters text-right">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h5 class="text-white">2</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 justify-content-sm-center justify-content-lg-center" style="margin: 0px;margin-top: 0px;padding: 10px;">
                    <div class="card bg-warning">
                        <div class="card-header" style="padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
                            <h6 class="text-truncate text-center text-white">Log</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body" style="opacity: 1;padding: 12px;">
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-truncate text-white">Hours</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-right" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-white">4 <i class="far fa-clock"></i></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h4 class="text-right text-white"></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h5 class="text-right text-white">50</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 justify-content-sm-center justify-content-lg-center" style="margin: 0px;margin-top: 0px;padding: 10px;">
                    <div class="card bg-info">
                        <div class="card-header" style="padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
                            <h6 class="text-truncate text-center text-white">Reviews</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body" style="padding: 12px;">
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-truncate text-white">Total</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-right" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-white">3.5 <i class="fa fa-star"></i></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row no-gutters text-right">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h5 class="text-white">145 Reviews</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div><a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col">
                    <div>
                        <form></form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You could also add different widths at the small screen size so instead of having just `col-sm-2` and `col-sm-10` main columns you could make them `col-md-2 col-sm-3` and `col-md-10 col-sm-9`

And here is an updated snippet with that change:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>



<div class="row no-gutters" style="margin-left: 15px;margin-right: 15px;">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-md navbar-expand-sm">
                <button id="filter_control" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#filter_container3" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <p><i class="fas fa-sliders-h" style="padding-right:5px;"></i>=More Settings&nbsp;</p>
                </button>
            <!--collapse for filter and flex-column to make narrow column-->
                <div id="filter_container3" class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="margin-top:50px;">
    
                    <div class="list-group text-secondary">
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="404.html"><span>Account</span></a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="account.html"><span>Subject</span></a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><span>Class</span></a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><span>Schedule</span></a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><span>Log</span></a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><span>Billing</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    
    
    <!--mid col-->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-sm-9">
            <div class="row no-gutters" style="margin-top:25px;">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 justify-content-sm-center justify-content-lg-center" style="margin: 0px;margin-top: 0px;padding: 10px;">
                    <div class="card bg-success">
                        <div class="card-header" style="padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
                            <h6 class="text-truncate text-center text-white">Appt</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body" style="padding: 12px;">
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-truncate text-white">Coming</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-right" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-white"><i class="far fa-calendar-check" style="opacity: 1;"></i></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row no-gutters text-right">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h5 class="text-white">4</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div><a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 justify-content-sm-center justify-content-lg-center" style="margin: 0px;margin-top: 0px;padding: 10px;">
                    <div class="card bg-primary">
                        <div class="card-header" style="padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
                            <h6 class="text-truncate text-center text-white">Messages</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body" style="padding: 12px;margin: 0px;">
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-truncate text-white">New</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-right" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-white"><i class="far fa-comment"></i></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row no-gutters text-right">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h5 class="text-white">2</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 justify-content-sm-center justify-content-lg-center" style="margin: 0px;margin-top: 0px;padding: 10px;">
                    <div class="card bg-warning">
                        <div class="card-header" style="padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
                            <h6 class="text-truncate text-center text-white">Log</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body" style="opacity: 1;padding: 12px;">
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-truncate text-white">Hours</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-right" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-white">4 <i class="far fa-clock"></i></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h4 class="text-right text-white"></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h5 class="text-right text-white">50</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 justify-content-sm-center justify-content-lg-center" style="margin: 0px;margin-top: 0px;padding: 10px;">
                    <div class="card bg-info">
                        <div class="card-header" style="padding-right: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px;">
                            <h6 class="text-truncate text-center text-white">Reviews</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body" style="padding: 12px;">
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-truncate text-white">Total</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col text-right" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
                                    <h5 class="text-white">3.5 <i class="fa fa-star"></i></h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row no-gutters text-right">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <h5 class="text-white">145 Reviews</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div><a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col">
                    <div>
                        <form></form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Anyway hope this helps.